# PHPSpreadsheet cell value duplicate for multiline value

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

I have a multi-line cell value that I am trying to insert into an Excel sheet. While using multiline value, the cell values are duplicated every 16 rows.

**For Example**

- IF there are a total of 16 rows. Every cell value will print properly ( https://prnt.sc/wPKKpNxthVl5 ).
- The total row is greater than 16 and less than or equal to 32. Then the cell value is printed times for rows 1 to 16 ( https://prnt.sc/lVmuiQ0OwqRI ), while other rows will have a single value ( https://prnt.sc/Xm5IJShAw3SJ ).
- There are more rows than 32 and less than or equal to 48. Then the cell value is printed 3 times for rows 1 to 16 ( https://prnt.sc/POWVZK1Yvncy ), 2 times for rows 17 to 32 ( https://prnt.sc/anTsJWomhdCv ), and 1 time for other rows.
- So on...

```php
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

$spreadSheetObject = new Spreadsheet();

$range = range(1, 34);
foreach ($range as $row) {
    $spreadSheetObject->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("A" . $row, "- Line1 \r\n - Line2");
}

$fileName = time().'.xlsx';

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadSheetObject, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save($fileName);
```

**Used versions of the code:**

- PHP: 8.1
- [phpoffice/phpspreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet): ^1.29

**Note**

- Issue only facing for new line like `- Line1 \r\n - Line2`
- For single line value working fine

[image]

Comment: You should instead of directly setting the cell value in the loop, try creating the multiline string first and then assigning it to the cell.

Comment: Let me try your suggestion.